# Задача про квадраты на C#

Tags: c#

не могу додуматься как сделать проверку того,что корень полный,помогите.
**Входные данные**
Вводятся целые числа a и b. Гарантируется, что a не превосходит b.
(2 8)
**Выходные данные**
Выведите все числа на отрезке от a до b, являющиеся полными квадратами. Если таких чисел нет, то ничего выводить не нужно.
(4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите картинку и вставьте ваш код как положено с форматированием пож.

Comment: Наверное, все же, не корень полный, а квадрат...

Answer (score 1):

Опишу алгоритм словесно, т.к. не знаю c#.

1. Организуем цикл от ближайшего сверху целого для sqrt(a) до
   ближайшего целого снизу для sqrt(b) с шагом один.
2. На каждой итерации выводим квадрат счетчика  цикла.

Собственно, все.

Answer (score 0):

```
Вычислить квадратный корень из числа, c использованием алгоритма разности. 
Алгоритм : из числа, корень которого нам нужен, по очереди вычитаются нечетные числа  до тех пор, пока остаток на выходе не получится меньше вычитаемого или вообще будет равен нулю. 
Количество ходов и станет в итоге искомым числом. Например, вычисление квадратного корня из 25: 25-1=24, 24-3=21, 21-5=17, 17-7=10, 10-9=1. 
всего было 5 итераций, следовательно квадратный корень из 25 = 5.
```

```cs
// целый корень - корень числа без дробных чисел, округление до меньших целых (3.9 = 3; 19.50125010 = 19)
using System;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число");
            int a= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число");
            int b= Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int sqrtA=0,sqrtB=0; //обнуление счетчиков, в конечном итоге эти счетчики будут целым корнем (целый корень 65=8)
            for (int i=1; i<Int32.MaxValue; i+=2){ //(i=1,3,5,7,9,13,15...) если (а>=i) тогда { a-i; количество иттераций(счетчик)+1; }
                if (a>=i){
                    a-=i;
                    sqrtA++;
                }
                else break;
            }
            for (int i=1; i<Int32.MaxValue; i+=2){ //(i=1,3,5,7,9,13,15...) если (b>=i) тогда { b-i; количество иттераций(счетчик)+1; }
                if (b>=i){
                    b-=i;
                    sqrtB++;
                } 
                else break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("целый корень числа а = {0}     целый корень числа b = {1}",sqrtA,sqrtB); //*для наглядности, можно удалить строку полностью
            for (int i=sqrtA;i<=sqrtB;i++){
                Console.Write(i+" ");// числа, лежащие в диапазоне от корня а до корня b  *для наглядности, можно удалить строку полностью
                Console.WriteLine(i*i); // "полные квадраты", лежащие в диапазоне от а до b
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


    }
}
```